# Can't access one of the disk drives in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am using an Acer laptop. Just now finished Windows 7 installation and  formatted the C drive only.

When trying to access one of my disk drives (some G:/) it says,

> problem starting 4#.ini. The specified module could not found

But memory is occupied and I can see a shortcut in it.

Comment: Click start > right click computer and click manage, then click disk management. And post a screenshot of that.

Answer (score 0):

That is a virus/malware infection symptom. Install a free antivirus like avast! or AVG and do a full system scan. You should be able to access all your drives after you have cleaned up your computer with the scan.

I've seen my fair share of computers that show exactly that and they all have had a virus.

Comment: I recommend MalwareBytes.

Comment: I have done full system scan with avast free antivirus but still having the problem. Plz help me.

Comment: Did avast! find any virus? If it did maybe you need to restore file and folder attributes.

Open **Windows Explorer** and go to **Folder Options - View** and select the option that says **Show hidden files, folders and drives**. Also deselect the option **Hide protected operating system files**.

If you can now see the files and folders you will need to use the command line to change all the file and folders attributes. Keep us updated.

Answer (score 0):

You never said if the AV scan (as suggested by @Rubenalamina) found any virus's - even if it did find a virus, it doesn't mean it's put the registry back to what it was!

If your machine has had a virus, then it's quite often best practice to do a reformat. Some times, traces of the virus remain (in the form of incomplete/new registry entries for example) and can keep causing a problem. You may be able to do a repair with the original W7 disc ([link to download W7 ISO](http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/)).